# Regex with wget?

Tags: wget

I'm using wget to download some useful website:

```
wget -k -m -r -q -t 1 http://www.web.com/
```

but I want replace some bad words with my own choice (like Yahoo pipes regex)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to regexp out words from within the page you are fetching with `wget`, you should pipe the output through `sed`.

For example:

```
wget -k -m -r -q -t 1 -O - http://www.web.com/ | sed 's/cat/dog/g' > output.html
```

Use the `-O -` flag to write the output to `stdout`, and the `-q` flag to make `wget` run in quiet mode.

Haven't got a shell atm to check my syntax but that should set you on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed -i`.

```
find www.web.com -type f -exec sed -i 's/word1\|word2\|word3//ig' {} +
```

word1, word2, word3, etc. are the words to delete.